# Detect new file added or modified existing files in a directory

Tags: java, servlet-3.0

There is a servlet java application in another machine with directory and  file with sub directory .now if in those directory new lines of text  or new  file has added. i  want to pulled out whenever there is any changes occurred.it would be appreciated any kind of idea for implementation java application

Comment: If you have any ideas then share those so that we can work around it to get a better solution @ALEX

Comment: @alex you can check size of each file and if their is change in size  then pull it to your machin if you have written your own code for that else you can use repositry like svn for that.

Comment: i am checking the current lastModifed value of a given file and compare it with the previous value in every 10mint. and send those data to that application which needed.is it right approach as i new to java. thanks @I'm_Pratik

Comment: servlet application which has to   detected new file added or modified existing files in a directory and sent those information to another servlet appliction through url and i am not using svn. thank you @Kandy do u have any idea to dectect or watch each directory .

Comment: @ALEX, are you using spring boot in your application ?

Comment: i am using servlet app @Jacob

Answer (score 0):

For doing like this process you need Schedule, and there is a lot of API for this. In the example below, i'll use `java.util.concurrent` library.(java 5)

***1- Schedule a process:***

```
    public class BeeperControl {
    
        private static final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler =
                Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
    
        public static void beepForAnHour() {
            final Runnable beeper = new Runnable() {
                public void run() { 
                           // do your stuff here
                        System.out.println("beep"); }
            };
            final ScheduledFuture<?> beeperHandle =
                    scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(beeper, 10, 10, SECONDS);
            scheduler.schedule(new Runnable() {
                public void run() { beeperHandle.cancel(true); }
            }, 60 * 60, SECONDS);
        }


    public static void main(String... args){

        beepForAnHour();
    }
}
```

***2- watch creating, deleting, moving and renaming files under D:\Temp, and should allow you to learn what you need:***

```
public class Foo3
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        FileSystem fs = FileSystems.getDefault();
        WatchService ws = fs.newWatchService();
        Path pTemp = Paths.get("D:/Temp");
        pTemp.register(ws, new WatchEvent.Kind[] {ENTRY_MODIFY, ENTRY_CREATE, ENTRY_DELETE}, FILE_TREE);
        while(true)
        {
            WatchKey k = ws.take();
            for (WatchEvent<?> e : k.pollEvents())
            {
                Object c = e.context();
                System.out.printf("%s %d %s\n", e.kind(), e.count(), c);
            }
            k.reset();
        }
    }
}
```

1- Schedule a process [Reference1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html)

2- watch creating     [Reference2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38063436/watching-for-file-and-directory-changes-in-java)

hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

I understand your problem statement so you should have `WatchService` in `java.nio` package.
`WatchService` allows registering a directory and any number of glob patterns. This class will take care of the filtering and only emit events you are interested in.

```
DirectoryWatchService watchService = new SimpleDirectoryWatchService(); // May throw
watchService.register( // May throw
        new DirectoryWatchService.OnFileChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFileCreate(String filePath) {
                // File created
            }

            @Override
            public void onFileModify(String filePath) {
                // File modified
            }

            @Override
            public void onFileDelete(String filePath) {
                // File deleted
            }
        },
        <directory>, // Directory to watch
        <file-glob-pattern-1>, // E.g. "*.log"
        <file-glob-pattern-2>, // E.g. "input-?.txt"
        ... // As many patterns as you like
);

watchService.start();
```

For a complete solution you can refer [GitHub](https://github.com/Hindol/commons) repo